# Prevent up/down arrow keys from changing focused select's selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a document with two `select` elements. I want the up/down arrow keys to always change only one of those `select`s, regardless of where the focus is. Even if the user just clicked into `select#two` and it still has focus, I want the up/down keys to change `select#one`.

Below is the code I have to control `select#one`. **Is it possible to make `select#two` never respond to up/down arrow key events?**

```
document.onKeyDown = function(e) {
    var evtobj = e.which ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;
    if (evtobj == 38) {
        e.preventDefault(); //do not scroll
        //change the selection
        select = $('select#one');
        select[0].selectedIndex = Math.max(0, select[0].selectedIndex - 1)
        select.change(); //fire change listeners
    } 
    if (evtobj == 40) {
        //ditto for up key
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to a jQuery solution?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville judging from `$('select#one')`, I think he's already using one

Comment: Oh, woops, missed that. Nice catch.

Comment: Have you considered using a list with some styling instead of a select tag?

Comment: @Chango I suppose that would work, but this is going into a large site that has a defined set of styled elements I'm allowed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A semi-hackerish solution is to blur all of the other select elements (e.g. `select#two` in this example) on the page when either of these key events happen: `$("select").blur()`. Perhaps the best/only solution...